# Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required. Error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to create the Vegetation Condition Index with Landsat time series images in Earth Engine, but I get the error:

> ImageCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=LC08_198032_20130813):
>   Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required.

Below is the script code, maybe something I was doing wrong at the section "//Create VCI index":

```
var l8collection = l8.filterDate('2013-04-01','2019-11-30').filterBounds(roi);
print(l8collection);

// Mask pixels with clouds and cloud shadows using the 'pixel_qa' band

var maskClouds = function(image){
// make a new single band image from the pixel qa band
  var pixel_qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // retain clear (0) and water (1) pixels
  return image.updateMask(pixel_qa.eq(322));   
};

// use "map" to apply the function to each image in the collection
var l8masked = l8collection.map(maskClouds);
print(l8masked);

// create function to add NDVI using NIR (B5) and the red band (B4)
var getNDVI = function(img1){
  return img1.addBands(img1.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// map over image collection
var l8ndvi = l8masked.map(getNDVI);

// filter images not containing data in the study area
var filtered = l8ndvi.filter(ee.Filter.neq('count', 0));

print(filtered);

// Create VCI index
var vci = filtered.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
  var min =  img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),geometry:roi, bestEffort:true, scale: 30}).get('NDVI');
 var max =  img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),geometry:roi, bestEffort:true, scale: 30}).get('NDVI');
 var Index = img.expression("(NDVI-min)/(max-min)",
 {"NDVI" : img,"max" : ee.Number(max),"min" : ee.Number(min),})
 .rename('TCI')
 .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
 return Index;
});
print(vci);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kevin Reid pointed out, the problem here is that the region reduction by `min` and/or `max` is resulting in `null`, which can occur when all the pixels in the region are masked. An alternative to reducing by `count` (as suggested) you can also pre-calculate min and max, add them as image properties and then filter on them to remove images from your collection that are `null`. This way you do not have to reduce the images an additional time for `count`. Here is an example script that illustrates the problem and provides a solution.

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/074fa04a0f910511be8d478debc8a053)

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */


// #############################################################################
// ### PROBLEM DEMO ###
// #############################################################################

// Define ROI.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-0.06057661456907226, 40.842476672518494],
    [-0.06057661456907226, 40.53424659065251],
    [0.36789018230592774, 40.53424659065251],
    [0.36789018230592774, 40.842476672518494]]], null, false);

// Import a sample image - set status.
var img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_198032_20130813')
  .set('status', 'noMask');

// Make a copy that is all masked - set status.
var imgAllMasked = img.gt(1e7).selfMask().set('status', 'allMask');

// Put images together in an image collection.
var l8collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([img, imgAllMasked]);

// Define a function to add NDVI using NIR (B5) and the red band (B4).
var getNDVI = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// Map NDVI function over the image collection.
var l8ndvi = l8collection.map(getNDVI);

// Subset just the 'allMask' image for testing with expression.
var allMasked = l8ndvi.filter('status == "allMask"').first();

// Define a combined reducer for min and max - one pass through the data.
var minMaxReducer = ee.Reducer.min().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

// Calculate regional min and max for the `allMasked` image.
var minMax =  allMasked.reduceRegion(
  {reducer: minMaxReducer, geometry:roi, bestEffort:true, scale: 30});

// Get the regional min and max NDVI values from the dictionary.
var min = minMax.get('NDVI_min');
var max = minMax.get('NDVI_max');
print('allMaskDemo min calc:', min); // null
print('allMaskDemo max calc:', max); // null

// Try using the expression function with null inputs; error occurs.
var allMaskDemo = allMasked.expression("(NDVI-min)/(max-min)", {
  "NDVI": allMasked,
  "max": ee.Number(max),
  "min": ee.Number(min),
});
print('allMaskDemo index calc:', allMaskDemo);



// #############################################################################
// ### SOLUTION ###
// #############################################################################

// Need to filter out all of the images that have null min or max region
// reductions. Map a function over the image collection that adds the min and
// max region reductions as image properties and then filter out the ones that
// are null.

// Calculate regional min and max and add as image properties.
l8ndvi = l8ndvi.map(function(img) {
  var minMax =  img.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: minMaxReducer, geometry:roi, bestEffort:true, scale: 30});
  return img.set({
    roi_min: minMax.get('NDVI_min'),
    roi_max: minMax.get('NDVI_max')
  });
});

// Filter out min and max region reductions that are null.
var filtered = l8ndvi
  .filterMetadata('roi_min', 'not_equals', null)
  .filterMetadata('roi_max', 'not_equals', null);

// Create VCI index.
var vci = filtered.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var max = img.getNumber('roi_max');
 var Index = img.expression("(NDVI-min)/(max-min)", {
    "NDVI": img.select('NDVI'),
    "min" : img.getNumber('roi_min'),
    "max" : img.getNumber('roi_max'),
 })
 .rename('VCI')
 .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
 return Index;
});
print('After filtering null min and max:', vci);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to understand the error message:

- In Earth Engine, an argument being `null` is usually the same as it being omitted. Hence, a call to `Image.constant` with the value `null` will produce the error `Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required.` This probably explains why you are getting this error despite not having written a misformed call to `Image.constant`.
- But you don't have any `Image.constant` in your script, it seems. What you do have is `img.expression("(NDVI-min)/(max-min)", ...)` and you are passing in numbers. This implicitly creates a call to `Image.constant` to convert those numbers to constant images.
- Therefore, we can conclude that either `min` or `max` were null. This could happen if for whatever reason there were no pixels intersecting the region of interest, so the minimum/maximum is undefined.

I confirmed this theory by using your `reduceRegion` parameters with `ee.Reducer.count()`: `img.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),geometry:roi, bestEffort:true, scale: 30})` and replacing the image computation with returning a feature holding these counts in the properties. This showed that some of the selected images (may not be the same as yours, since I didn't use the same `roi` which you did not include in your question) had `NDVI` bands that had zero pixels counted.

In order to avoid this error, you can `map` to add the results of the reductions as properties to the features, `filter` out features with null values with `ee.Filter.notNull`, then `map` to compute the result you want (see [Justin Braaten's answer](/questions/345972/image-constant-parameter-value-is-required-error-in-google-earth-engine/345975#345975) for code).